# iOS: Keep track of the sequence of NSSet objects

Tags: ios, model, nsmutablearray, nsset, xcdatamodel

I want have a variable NSSet photos and it stores the photos randomly in my Xcode xcdatamodel. I know NSSet is use to store random object but is there a way to either change the NSSet to NSArray or keep track of the sequence insert in the NSSet variable?

Article.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *photos;
```

Article.m

```
RKManagedObjectMapping *_mapping = (RKManagedObjectMapping*)[RKManagedObjectMapping generatedManagedObjectMappingFromClass:[self class] keyUnderscored:NO excludesProperties:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"attachments", @"videos", @"photos", nil]];
[_mapping mapKeyPath:@"photos.photo" toRelationship:@"photos" withMapping:(RKManagedObjectMapping*)[BTAttachment rkObjectMapping]];
[_mapping mapKeyPath:@"attachments.attachment" toRelationship:@"attachments" withMapping:(RKManagedObjectMapping*)[BTAttachment rkObjectMapping]];
```

**[Updated]**:

I realise even if I used

```
[_model.photos allObjects] objectAtIndex:0]
```

The 0 index still changing every time I refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NSOrderedSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) maintains the order.

You can also use [setWithArray:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSSet/setWithArray%3a) and [allObjects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSet/allObjects) to transform back and forth between NSSet and NSArray

Comment: The 0 index still changing every time I refresh.

Comment: even with NSOrderedSet?

Comment: Thanks! Discovered that I need to change the attribute of the relationship to change from NSSet to NSOrderedSet.